# Problems with Cherrypy on Windows 8 (Python)

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have successfully installed cherrypy but when I try to import it, I get following error. I am a newbie and have spent quite a bit of time trying to get this to work, so any help would be highly appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unitconverter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cherrypy
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy-3.2.0-py3.4.egg\cherrypy\__init__
.py", line 82, in <module>
    from cherrypy import process
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy-3.2.0-py3.4.egg\cherrypy\process\
__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cherrypy.process import plugins, servers
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy-3.2.0-py3.4.egg\cherrypy\process\
plugins.py", line 424, in <module>
    class PerpetualTimer(threading._Timer):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_Timer'
```

Comment: Thanks Makoto, I needed to upgrade CherryPy as you suggested.

Comment: Indeed. However, do not try the windows installer, I think it's broken. Rely on the zip package instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [what I can see](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310079/install-cherrypy-for-python3-3), it's a bug with that version of CherryPy.  You'd be best upgrading to a more recent version instead.